# On the Method of Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I was reading through Brauer's Ordinary Differential Equations book, specifically the section on the Method of Undetermined Coefficients or of Judicious Guess and I came across the following passage:

$\bbox[lightgrey,5px]{\text{ [...] However, there is a quicker way to solve the equation $L_n(y) = f$ provided that $L_n$ has constant }}$
$\bbox[lightgrey,5px]{\text{ coefficients and provided that f has a rather special form. Namely, we assume that $f$ is defined on$\ $ }}$
$\bbox[lightgrey,5px]{\text{$-\infty \lt t \lt \infty $ and has at most  a finite number of linearly independent derivatives. This is $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $}}$
$\bbox[lightgrey,5px]{\text{ equivalent to assuming that f must satisfy some homogeneous linear differential equation with $\ \ \ \ \ \ $}}$
$\bbox[lightgrey,5px]{\text{coefficients. Therefore, it must be in fact assumed that $f(t)$ is a linear combination of terms of the $\ $ }}$
$\bbox[lightgrey,5px]{\text{form $t^ke^{mt}$ where $k\ge0$ is an integer and $m$ is a real or complex number including possibly zero.$\ \ \ \ $ }}$

My question does not really have to do with the method, but rather an assertion not proved. I did not quite understand why the fact that $f$ has at most a finite number of linearly independent derivatives implies that $f$ must be a linear combination of functions of the form $t^ke^{mt},$ with $ k\in \mathbb{Z} $ and$\ m\in \mathbb{C}$.

Any references of where I can find this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't that it has a finite number of linearly independent coefficients; rather, it has a finite number of linearly independent derivatives.

In other words, there is a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{(0)},f^{(1)},\ldots,f^{(n-1)}$ are linearly independent functions, but any further derivatives can be written in terms of them.

This means that, in particular, there are coefficients $a_0,\ldots,a_n$ such that
$$
a_0f+a_1f^{(1)}+\cdots+a_{n}f^{(n)}=0.
$$
But, this is precisely a linear, homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients.

So, as long as you believe that linear homogeneous differential equations with constant coefficients have solutions built from terms of the form $t^ke^{mt}$, this settles the question.

As for why THIS is true:

The way that I've usually seen this explained is in terms of polynomial differential operators.  We can write the above equation as
$$
a_0f+a_1Df+\cdots +a_{n}D^{n}f=0,
$$
where $D$ is the standard differential operator; we can then write this as
$$
P(D)f=0,\qquad P(D)=a_0+a_1D+a_2D^2+\cdots+a_{n}D^{n}.
$$
Think of this polynomial with a variable input instead of $D$: say $P(y)=a_0+a_1y+\cdots+a_{n}y^{n}$. We know that this can be factored as
$$
P(y)=\alpha\prod_{i=1}^{k}(y-c_i)^{p_i}
$$
for some (possibly complex) $c_1,\ldots,c_k$ and positive integers $p_1,\ldots,p_k$.

The general outline for the proof is:

1. Show that if $P_1(D)f=0$, then $P_1(D)P_2(D)f=0$ as well. (In other words: we can solve the factors of the polynomial differential operator.)
2. Show that $e^{c_it},te^{c_it},\ldots,t^{k-1}e^{c_it}$ are solutions of $(D-c)^{k}f=0$, when $c\in\mathbb{C}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
3. Combining (1) and (2), you now have $n$ candidate solutions to $P(D)f=0$.  Show that they are linearly independent.
4. Show that the solutions to $P(D)f=0$ form a vector space with dimension at most $n$.

That finishes it: (3) and (4) combined show you that these forms of solution form a basis for the vector space of all solutions, so that any solution can be written as a linear combination of these candidate solutions.

Comment: I actually typed it wrong

Comment: I just edited it, sorry

Comment: What I actually wanted to know is precisely the part "So, as long as you believe that linear homogeneous differential equations with constant coefficients have solutions built from terms of the form $t^ke^{mt}$"

Comment: I've added an outline of the proof.  Let me know what you think.